# Diode Circuits Help

Tags: diodes, graph

[image]

1) Assuming the input is expressed as Vin = V0
cos ωt, plot the output of each circuit in the figure below
as a function of time. Use an ideal diode model. In the following problems, assume VB=2 V

Hello All. Can someone explain how we go about with these types of questions. Any links for information related to this problems is apreciated

Comment: If we don't understand the question we usually ask the instructor to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a graph of the output signal with D1 disconnected.

Now take what you have learned about how a diode functions. What happens to the signal when the diode is NOT conducting?

What happens to the signal when the diode IS conducting?

When does the diode begin to conduct? When does it stop conducting?

You should be able to sketch the final output waveform easily.